# Can I restrict viewing some documents from a controlled documents library?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

We have around 2000 files in our sharepoint controlled document library, which are viewable by everyone. I would like to restrict viewing of some of the documents and make them viewable for only a specific group of users. I am aware that it can be done by moving those documents to another library and using document library permission, but I prefer to do it programatically by using a document property to identify them
Is it possible to programatically deny access to some documents inside the controlled documents library?

Answer (score 1):

An ok approach to achieve this could be to implement an HTTP module that returns a 401 for the URLs matching the documents you want to block. Users will still be able to see all documents in the list view (allitems.aspx for instance) and the associated metadata on view/edit item - also those documents they do not have access to.

As SharePoint alternative you could also set item specific permissions in the document library - without splitting it up into folders or multiple document libraries. That of course implies that you can use assign specific users or groups to the items.

Kr., Bernd.

Comment: thanks for your reply. you are right, i tried sharepoint alternative, but i cannot choose to deny users

Comment: do you mean http handler or event handler?

Comment: No, I was thinking of an HTTP Module that plugs into the HTTP pipeline and can 'do something' on all requests send to the application. It is registered in web.config. Here is a reference to an article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx